# Car won’t accelerate after heavy rain flooded in my car

Tags: transmission, pontiac, stall, acceleration

Ok, so my car was left with the windows cracked and sunroof cracked awhile I was out of town for a day, when I got back the next day I found my car with like a ton of water on the floors and my seats wet and dash wet. And I got in after vacuuming the water off the floors and dried the dash ect and the car drove and 20 yards and than when coming to a red light stalled after pushing the break. I pulled the car over and started it and tried again with the same outcome.  I turned my car on and let it run for a couple of moments and shortly after I tried to drive around a parking lot ( note: I was sorta stranded and needed to see if it was able to get me home that’s about 10 miles away ) 
But after driving it around the parking lot it didn’t stall and drove fine  so I tried again and soon to realize the car wouldn’t accelerate and took a while to get passed first and second gear. It didn’t stall but I would ease the gas just enough to let me get to 40 mph. I made it home and tried to test it and it just started to stall again.

The car has power and turns over fine and doesn’t have any issues in parked just as soon as I go into drive and tap the break it stalls immediately. I don’t know if it will accelerate properly due to not trying but idk if anyone knows if the water could of caused this?

The car is 05 Pontiac g6
Note: the car didn’t have any lights in before hand and didn’t give no signs of bad tranny or engine before hand but when starting the car for the first time after seeing the water damage inside it had the tire pressure and check engine light on.

Comment: Does the car have a whole load of electrics under the carpet in the passenger footwell? They may still be flooded.